# pandas datareader - How to send quandl api key?

Tags: pandas, quandl, pandas-datareader

Here is my code

```
df = pdr.DataReader(quan, 'quandl', start, end, access_key="Mykey")
```

I get the following error:

> Response Text:
>   b'code,message\n"QELx01","You have exceeded the anonymous user limit of 50 calls per day. To make more calls today, please register for a free Quandl account and then include your API key with your requests."'

Am I send the `key` incorrectly?

I have tried

```
df = pdr.DataReader(quan, 'quandl', start, end, api_key="Mykey")
```

Same error.

Comment: Looks like a bug: https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/484

Comment: @bernie Thanks, I have decided to use `pd.read_csv(url)` as the solution. It seems simpler and more robust than hardcoding in quandl. For anyone who is also having this issue the structure can be found here https://blog.quandl.com/api-for-stock-data